# DatePicker adds 1 hour in Chrome

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, kendo-ui, datepicker, hour

I have a Kendo DatePicker on frontend and when i try to sumbit a date, it adds 1 hour when catched on the backend.

It's a DatePicker (not DateTime) and backend (in C# MVC) uses DateTime property. When selecting for example 16.06.1953, on the backend I get 16.06.1953 01:00:00 (instead of 00:00:00).

This only happens to Dates before 1980 and in months from march to october.
16.11.1953 returns time 00:00:00.

I have encoutered this problem in Chrome, IE works fine.

EDIT: CET timezone.
There is this javascript that handles kendo datepicker date:

```
$(function () {
    var form = $("form");
    var dateBirthField = $("#Filter_DateBirth");

    if (dateBirthField.prop("defaultValue")) {
        var date = new Date(dateBirthField.prop("defaultValue"));
        if (!isNaN(date)) {
            dateBirthField.data("kendoDatePicker").value(date);
        }
    }

    form.submit(function () {
        var dateElement = dateBirthField.data("kendoDatePicker");

        if (!dateElement) {
            return;
        }
        var date = dateElement.value();
        if (date && !isNaN(date)) {
            dateBirthField.val(date.toISOString());
        }
    });
});
```

EDIT 2: So, Javascript date correctly differs +1 or +2 hourse in 1970 and 1980 (summer time was added in 1979), but backend application adds those two hours.
So:

```
date.toISOString()
```

results in "1953-06-15T23:00:00.000Z", so it decreases by 1 hour but the application than incorrectly adds 2 hours, instead of 1.
How am I supposed to deal with this?

Comment: [quoot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summer_time_in_Europe), "Austria used summer time in ...., and since 1980." you are in Austria ?

Comment: CZE, same as austria

Comment: try to convert your starting date to `DateTime.UtcNow()`. UTC does not care about summertime....